Arrow symbols are 180deg off rotation in QGIS
I'm using QGIS 3.36, and I have a layer of geotagged images that I've marked with arrows. I've rotated the arrows with the images exif data and while they're all rotating, I've noticed they're reversed, or 180deg different than what they should be. The arrow points one way, but the image was taken facing the exact opposite direction.
I'm using the "direction" field to do the rotation. How can I correct for the discrepancy so the arrows are facing the proper direction?

Add or subtract 180 from them, there clearly a disagreement about which direction to measure from

@IanTurton Is there a way to do that in QGIS so I don't have to manually change the EXIF data on thousands of images one at a time, or without having to write a script to do that every time I add new? All I've done is for the rotation field is select the available variable, but it doesn't look like there's an option for a formula.

If you click on the data defined override button (to the right of the text box) you can select edit and that will take you to the Expression editor where you can write an expression to give you the direction you need.


That did it, thank you! Still getting used to all the different places I can get to an expression editor.
